# Facebook events 500 internal server error

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to upload a cover photo for my Facebook event but when I click on the button to upload cover photo the menu doesn't come up. When I check the console I'm getting this error,

https://www.facebook.com/ajax/events/cover/photo_selector.php?profile_id=**the event id** Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

How can I fix this? I've waited for 2 days and there is no change.

Comment: If this is Facebook's code and not your own, what makes you think you can "fix" it? I just created a test event and I can set the cover photo just fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic this is not Facebook's technical support.